# jQuery AJAX post with fileupload

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, post, file-upload

I have a functional page posting data to a Page WebMethod

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string sayHello(string pTest, string pText)
{
  return pTest + " - " + pText;
}
```

which I call using this jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#sayHelloButton").click(function (event) {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var text = $('#text').val(); 
    var dataString = JSON.stringify({
      pTest: name,
      pText: text
    }); 

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "page.aspx/sayHello",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: dataString,
      dataType: "json",
      success: AjaxSucceeded,
      error: AjaxFailed,
      beforeSend: AjaxStart,
      complete: AjaxEnd
    });
  });
});
```

but now it should also be possible to upload a file and here I am a bit lost.

From what I can read in different posts in here it is not possible but please correct me if I am wrong - but I have seen several jQuery plugins which make upload possible, e.g. through a Flash-script, but how will it then be possible to both post data and upload with only one click? Does anyone have any suggestions which upload plugin is best - and how i can succeed in upload and post in one action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell for all plugins, but I'm using jQuery Form without any problems. No flash involved, it just creates hidden iframe instead.

[Here's a demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload).

*but how will it then be possible to both post data and upload with only one click*
The process is the same as with normal ajax request. You declare a form element, but instead of `$('#myform').submit();` do `$('#myform').ajaxSubmit()`.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but if i do as you suggest and I use ASP.NET which have only 1 form-tag i guess it submits a lot of irrelevant stuff (e.g. viewstate and elements belonging to another part of the page) making the operation slower and that I cannot target a WebMethod with specific parameters as in my example?

Comment: @keysersoze By default, yes. I would try creating a hidden form from javascript and attach your file input to it (temporary). But never had to solve this problem, so no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `sayHelloButton` is the id of the submission button on the form you are using to upload the file, be sure to add: `event.preventDefault();` to your  `$("#sayHelloButton").click()` function or use `javascript.void();` on the form to prevent the browser from posting the data using its default behavior.  Otherwise, your ajax code will never even execute.

```
$("#sayHelloButton").click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var name = $('#name').val();
var text = $('#text').val(); 
var dataString = JSON.stringify({
  pTest: name,
  pText: text
});
```