# Unable to validate file upload in Laravel 4 when request is ajax

Tags: php, laravel

I have this piece of code in my **BaseModel** inside the **validate** method:

```
foreach(Input::file() as $key => $value)
{
    (!empty($value)) ? $this->attributes[$key] = Input::file($key) : $this->attributes[$key] = '';
}
```

This allows me to integrate file validation with the rest of the input validation. Using the rules `required` and `mimes:png` it works as it should.

However, for ajax requests I always receive `$this->attributes[$key] = ''`.

Is there any catch when uploading files via ajax in Laravel 4?

Comment: Can we see your upload script?

Comment: Assuming it's your upload script, not Laravel.  You can't simply send files over the usual ajax request.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706857/how-to-see-the-files-uploaded-in-a-form-with-ajax/18707003#18707003

Comment: Ok Nathan, your information answer my question.

Comment: @NathanLoding Please convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's your upload script, not Laravel. You can't simply send files over the usual ajax request. [How to see the Files uploaded in a form with ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706857/how-to-see-the-files-uploaded-in-a-form-with-ajax/18707003#18707003)