# How to handle ajax call in laravel controller functions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I perform an ajax call to a laravel controller, but it seems not working. What can I do?

```
public function postSubmit($id) {//Gelen geornal id'si

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $uploaded = [];
    $allowed = ['jpg', 'png'];

    $succeeded = [];
    $failed = [];

    if(!empty($_FILES['dosya'])) {

           // It seems not entering here.. I want to save file here.

    }
```

When I write that in controller:

```
$allFiles = Input::all();
return $allFiles;
```

I get this in my console:

```
Object {ajax: "true", file: Array[1]}
```

How can I get my file in controller?

This is the script:

```
<script>

    document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var f = document.getElementById('file_input'),

        app.uploader({
            files: f,
            processor: "{{ URL::route('category/post', array($category->id)) }}",

        });

    });


</script>
```

And I have getFormData and ajax function to get FormData and for a XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: what are you trying to do, and what have you tried?

Comment: what is error you are getting? please also show your routes.php file

Comment: I want to save form file.

Comment: There is no problem in route file. Ajax call works.

Comment: You can't have file upload over an usual ajax request. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18707033/2094178

Comment: I use FormData. I updated my question.