# Submit form (django-form) with Imagefield via Jquery/Ajax Post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, imagefield

Im having some problems submitting a form (Django-form) with a imagefield with Jquery/ajax POST. Im getting back "Field required" validation errors on the imagefield..

I been trying different solutions with appending formData but with no results so far. Am i on the right track? Please point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Update: I can set the imagefield to required=false and not get the validation error but i want the field to be required and it seems like the form still doesn't submit the image..

The basic function looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#imageupload').on('click', function() { 

        $('#dialog-modal').load('upload/ #myform');

        $('#dialog-modal').dialog({
              height: 550,
              width: 280,
              modal: true,

              buttons: {
                    Send: function() { 
                        var dialog = $(this), 
                            form = $('#myform'),
                            data = form.serialize();

                    $('.off').remove(); 

                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: 'upload/',
                        data: data,
                        type: 'post',

                        success: function(response) {
                            res = $.parseJSON(response);

                            if (res['status'] == 'OK') {
                                alert('Thank you!'); 
                                dialog.dialog('close'); 
                            }

                            else if (res['status'] == 'bad') {
                                alert('Please try again!');
                                delete res['status'] 
                                var errors = res;

                                $.each(errors, function(key, value) {

                                    var err = $('<span></span>', {
                                                    'class': 'off',
                                                    'text': value
                                            }),
                                        br = $('<br></br>', {
                                            'class': 'off',
                                        }),
                                        input = $('#id_'+key).parent(); 

                                    br.appendTo(input);

                                    err.appendTo(input);

                                    err.css('color', 'red').css('font-size', '10px');

                                });
                            }
                        }

                      });

                    }
                  }
            });


    });
})
```

Form looks like this, it's in a child html wich is loaded into a jquery dialog/modal box:

```
    <form method="post" id='myform' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1> Upload </h1>
    <p><label for="name">Name:</label></p>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.name }}
    </div>  
    <br>
    <p><label for="type">Type:</label></p> 
    <div class="fieldWrapper">                
    {{ form.type }}
    </div> 
    <br>
    <p><label for="description">Description:</label></p>  
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.description }}
    </div>  
    <br>  
    <p><label for="picture">Picture:</label></p> 
    <div class="fieldWrapper">                
    {{ form.picture }}
    </div> 
    </form>
```

Comment: Yeah actually, it seems that file uploads through ajax are not supported. There are some [plugins](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/) and [examples](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) out there that show how to work around this limitation. Try to understand how to use them. If you don't find a solution, I'll figure it out when I find the time

Comment: Ok. Yes i've seen some say that but also a lot of people who claims it is possible (which has been a little confusing). One way should be something called formData which i've been trying with the last days without any good results. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files But I'll try more on the plug-ins and see!

Comment: I turned out to be easier than I thought, using the malsup plugin

Comment: Damn you're fast man! Which plug-in was that?

Comment: look at the answer =]

Comment: Haha always one step ahead! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a known issue with file uploads through jQuery ajax. There are [tons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery/8244082#8244082) [of solutions](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) [and plugins](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/) [out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925816/jquery-ajax-post-with-fileupload), most of them using [an iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp). However, I think the [malsup jQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) provides the easiest of them all, with only a slight modification to your code:

add this inside `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

change the code within the `Send` function like so:

```
buttons: {
    Send: function() { 
        $('.off').remove();
        var dialog = $(this),
            options = {
                url: 'upload/',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    // everything the same in here
                    }
                };

        $('#myform').ajaxSubmit(options);

    }
  }
```

Of course, on the server-side you need to make sure to [follow the instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files) from the documentation on how to bind the files to your form. For the most basic usage, it generally boils down to this:

```
form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

p.s. one final note - as mentioned, it's a known issue, and the solution from malsup uses something called [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/). It's simply a newer API which provides more functionality to AJAX requests like file uploads, transfer progress information and the ability to send form data. My point being, [older browsers don't support it](http://caniuse.com/xhr2), so bare in mind that if you want legacy-browser-users to make use of your site, you'll need to find an alternative.

Comment: Im trying to get this one to work! Not quite there yet. But I'm optimistic! A lot of } and }; right now that needs to be in the right places! I let you know how it works out! Thanks for your complete answer!!

Comment: Finally!! It works! Right now I really don't care if older browsers can support it.. So glad it just works! Can't thank you enough for this man!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've a required attribute on the image field and you're not stopping default behaviour for click function.

```
$('#imageupload').on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
```

Bit hard to tell without your HTML code... You should ideally use a form with an id then target that element to bind to the 'submit' event so Enter key and touch events are also handled by the same code.

```
$('#imageform').on('submit', function (e){ e.preventDefault() // other code here }
```

See also: [Ajax Upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for yout answer. Don't think it's required but even if it was it should pass that error if i've choosen a file to upload (?). Thats my idea anyway. That you should have to post a picture and if you do the field should pass the validation. I'll try with the prevent default.